# How to add 18.04 repo to 20.04?

Tags: apt, dhcp

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi 4, the only officially available LTS version of Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi 4.

I would also like to run isc-dhcp-server on it however it keeps crashing due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1872106). It hasn't been fixed for 2 months so I need to work around it.

The solution apparently is to install isc-dhcp-server from ubuntu Bionic repo instead of Focal, but how do I do it?

One solution would be to just get dpkg however this means no security updates via apt. I would like to add bionic repo to my Ubuntu 20.04 and make isc-dhcp-server the only package that is being updated from it.

How do I do it?

Alternatively, if someone has a better idea on how to install working version of isc-dhcp-server on Ubuntu 20.04 that will allow me to easily keep it up to date I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically it is possible to add bionic source list.
You can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` file for it and replace `focal` with `bionic` for main repositories. **I would not recommend this way as it will result in broken dependency tree.**

To work around you can try downloading .deb package from [Bionic repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/). Here again it will not work without its dependencies and libraries may be conflict. **Try it on your own risk.** **This is also not recommended way.**   You need to wait until bug is fixed for Ubuntu 20.04 as of now.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot switch back 18.04 because it is not officially supported by Raspberry Pi 4. Oldest I can go back to is 19.10.

Is there maybe some official isc-dhcp-server repo other than ubuntu's that is being kept up to date?

Answer (score 4):

It might be as simple as adding the line `deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main` to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic.list`, installing the bionic package and then using pinning or some other technique to prevent the reinstallation of the focal package.

If there's too much technical jargon in those sentences then it might be advisable not to try and pursue that route.  Quite certainly it can result in a messed up system unless you understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

This is a direct snippet, but I must discourage from this approach as it might destabilize/put your system out of balance. Rather try to look on internet for a PPA for a package for your release or a direct download.

This single command, followed by an `sudo apt update` should suffice

```
release=bionic; cat > "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/$release.list"<<EOF
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $release-security main
EOF
```

You can search for a specific package being comprised by a specific release on the ubuntu package site, opting a specific release and package: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=search

Comment: Do you think this is advisable?

Comment: @OrganicMarble you are right honestly, I updated the answer